# Throwing an exception when failing to resolve a dependency

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Consider the following class:

```
public class ComponentA
{
    public ComponentB ComponentB { get; set; }

    public ComponentA(ComponentC componentC) { ... }
}
```

When I resolve a `ComponentA`, Castle injects both `ComponentB` and `ComponentC` correctly.

However, if there is a problem instantiating `ComponentB`, it swallows the exception, resulting in delayed errors (NullReferenceException).

I understand the difference between both approaches, but is it possible to make it fail (or at least log the full exception) when there is a problem with an injected property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Mauricio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398101/castle-windsor-strange-behaviour-wth-property-injection-and-factory-method/4401290#4401290) to the question linked by Phil, I created a `StrictComponentActivator` which does not swallow the exception even if the dependency is optional.

Works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I believe this is expected behavior, and AFAIK there is no way around it.</strike>

An option might be to use a private member for ComponentB that gets set to a default implementation (that throws an exception when accessed if that's what is needed), but gets overridden by the container if resolution is successful.

```
private ComponentB _b = new ExceptionThrowingComponentB();

public ComponentB B
{
   get { return _b; }
   set { _b = value; }
}
```

As svick noted: not a good solution.

**Edit:** I'm not sure I understand what all is involved, but it sounds like you can change this behavior:

[Castle Windsor strange behaviour wth property injection and factory method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398101/castle-windsor-strange-behaviour-wth-property-injection-and-factory-method)

Comment: How is exception throwing implementation different from `null`, that always throws an exception when trying to use it too?

Comment: Eh, you're right, there really isn't.  I started with a default/no-op implementation (which is the way I usualy do it) and then realized he wanted an exception thrown.